# I want to append to a file from an array

Tags: bash

I have an array of items I want to check within a .gitignore file so I can get all my hosts with the same version of .gitignore as I push my /etc into a git repo for backup.

The problem came in when I need to deal with a * after a /. It will keep adding the "sudoers.d/*-sssd" line to the .gitignore but not the *.bak and *.bkp as intended. If tried various things like escaping the * or using single quotes but I can't get the script to only add the entry if missing from .gitignore.

```
w_uname=$(which uname)
_uname=$($w_uname)
if [[ "$_uname" == 'Linux' ]]; then
    _gitignore=( "# Extra Additions" "*.bak" "*.bkp" "sudoers.d/*-sssd" )
    for i in "${_gitignore[@]}";
        do
            grep "$i" /etc/.gitignore 2>&1
            if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
                echo "$i" >> /etc/.gitignore
                _git_change=1
            fi
        done
fi

    if [[ _git_change -eq 1 ]]; then
        cd /etc/
        git add .gitignore
        git commit -m "updated .gitignore"
        git push
        echo ""
        echo ".gitignore updated."
        echo ""
    fi
```

Content of .gitignore with duplicates :

```
# Extra Additions
*.bak
*.bkp
sudoers.d/\*-sssd
sudoers.d/\*-sssd
```

Comment: use `grep -F` . And `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]` is an antipattern, just `if ! grep -q something; then`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for spotting the issue with grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the grep interprets the parameter as regular expression. `sudoers.d/*-sssd` is interpreted as `"sudoers.d" + <any number of '/'> + "-sssd"` so there is no match. But the parameter is a wildcard and not a regex in reality. You can either transform the wildcard to regex somehow but it is quite complex. The simplest solution is to force grep to interpret the pattern as a plain string.

From man grep:

> -F, --fixed-strings
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead  of  regular  expressions),  separated  by
> newlines, any of which is to be matched.

So change the grep to

```
grep -F "$i" /etc/.gitignore 2>&1
```